# string.match and regex in Lua, is it possible?

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching

I'm currently working on a script gathering information from a website.  I'm wondering if string.match would be able to accept regex pattern matching, such as the following:

```
string.match(page, "(?:(Phrase One|Phrase Two|Phrase Three|...))")
```

The problem is, I don't know if it can be done, but I'm willing to try any solutions.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could make a wrapper that parses the pattern with gmatch. If libraries are allowed, you could also use [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html)

Comment: The reason for not including regular expressions in the Lua standard library is that a full regular expression engine is bigger than the whole Lua language. Thus you either would need to implement this yourself in Lua, or use some C library delivered (and provided for Lua) by the program in which you are embedding.

Comment: Wound up using Jane's solution, and it's working perfectly.  Had to make some modifications to fit my needs, but that does the job.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is to define a function which takes your patterns as a table and then returns a table of matches, or if you only need to know if the text is contained in the page then following would work.

```
    function FindAny(strContent,tblPatterns)
    bReturn = false
    for i,strPattern in ipairs(tblPatterns) do
        if (string.find(strContent,strPattern) ~= nil) then
            bReturn = true
            break
        end
    end
    return bReturn
end
if FindAny('pattern 4',{'pattern 1','pattern 2','pattern 3','pattern 4'}) then
    print('Pattern Found')
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Lrexlib](http://rrthomas.github.com/lrexlib/) if you need full blown regular expressions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be compatible with the program I use (CMUD, used for Multi-User Dungeons).  That's a shame, because I definitely could do a lot with this, but apparently it only utilises the basic of the lua library, I guess, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ah you didn't say embedded Lua.

Comment: Actually, I learned something about the program and lua in general just today, and that was the usage of "require."  Now I just need to figure out how to make it require properly. :P

Answer (score 2):

Lua doesn't come with regular expressions built-in but there are a couple add-on modules for that. Here's one: http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/re.html

That said, gmatch() can be used for the problem you describe, it's just a different syntax than regular expressions. Here are explanations:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial

http://www.wowpedia.org/Pattern_matching

Comment: Unless I'm completely blind, I still fail to see how I can do multiple parameters with even gmatch.  Maybe I should have pointed out that the phrases are all different, such as "Results" or "Decimal approximation," etc.  That would be my fault here.

Comment: oh I didn't notice that you have multiple parameters in the regex. In that case I would do what @jane suggests: put all the parameters into a table and then loop through that table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial indicates in the gsub method.

Comment: I don't see where it allows for multiple parameters, though, which is what I need to do so I'm not doing 'if then else' statements for 15-20 different possible outputs... :\